# Ubuntu screen turning to blue

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

i have ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and i don't know why it's applying blue filter to the screen and i don't know how to turn it back to normal. And i can't access my settings[image]

Comment: Is this the same in BIOS? Is this a desktop monitor? Could you try a different HDMI cable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your monitor's color profile under:
Settings -> Color

Then restart your system and the colors should return to normal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).